# Ruby Looping Arrays over Eachother

Tags: ruby, arrays, comparison

I have two different arrays and I need a method to return to me the following:

```
array_1 = [1,2,3]
array_2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

def letter_to_number()
 #what goes here?
end

letter_to_number("g") #return 1
letter_to_number("a") #return 1
letter_to_number("b") #return 2
letter_to_number("f") #return 3
```

I'm not happy with any of the ways I came up with how to do this. I feel like there may be an easier way.

Comment: Well what are your ways? And what is that method even supposed to do?

Comment: You need to state the question. If I understand it correctly, it would be something like this: "If a given letter is located at offset `i` of `array_2`, return the value that is at offset `(i % array_1.size)` in `array_1`. Mind you, if that's correct, the answer is obtained by merely writing down what I've just said. :-)

Comment: Why is 'g' related to 1? Why is 'a'? We need to understand why they are related or what machinations to go through to end up with those results. Without that information it's a guessing game and we don't play those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you mean get the number like this:

```
array1(repeat):  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
array2:          a b c d e f g
```

You can get the letter's index in `array_2`, calculate the modulus (`%`) by the length of the `array_1`, and get the value in `array_1` with this index:

```
array_1[array_2.index("g") % array_1.length]
# => 1
```

I'll leave how to make a method like this to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, letter)
  array_1[array_2.index(letter) % array_1.size]
end

array_1 = [1,2,3]
array_2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "g") #=> 1
letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "a") #=> 1
letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "b") #=> 2
letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "f") #=> 3


array_1 = [1,2,3,4]
array_2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "g") #=> 3
letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "a") #=> 1
letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "b") #=> 2
letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, "f") #=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are correct, except a corner case needs to be handled, as shown below.

```
def letter_to_number(array_1, array_2, char)
  index = array_2.index(char) 
  (index)? array_1[index % array_1.length] : -1
end
```